# Calculating floating points within a range

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a vector(array) of floating points between -1.0 and 1.0.

I want to represent these visually in a range of e.g. 0 - 100 pixels.

Sometimes the floating points are centred around 0.0 so the graph shows small lines. I would like to normalise this somehow so that whether the values were larger (towards 1.0) or smaller (around 0.0) the graphs would still display large enough in the 0 - 100 pixels space.

How is this calculated?

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach would be to find $a$, the minimum of your values and $b$, the maximum of your values.  Then you display value $x$ as $100 \frac {x-a}{b-a}$  This will work well unless most (but not all) of your values are clustered, but there are outliers near $-1$ and $+1$.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work visually, the representation is pretty much normalized to the same value (the full range of the pixel count of the height)

Comment: Yes, I was spreading it over the whole 100 pixels.  I thought that was what you wanted.  You can change the multiplier of 100 to change the range, though it will start at zero.  If you want it to be centered, you can add on an appropriate amount.